# Version numbers for CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have inherited code from old contractors overseas.  The cakephp version I see is:

CakePHP v 0.2.9

Where does this fit in? Does it predate 1.0 or is this some 2.0 convention?

Comment: the 0.2.9 is "since", i.e. when the class/file was first introduced

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Simplest way to find current version is

```
echo Configure::version();
```

Answer (score 59):

The current version number of Cake 2.0 can be found in `/path/to/cake/lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`. The txt file contains a commented block containing the file description (stating that it has been there since Cake 0.2.9), followed by the actual version number.

The same file may be found in Cake 1.3 in `/path/to/cake/cake/VERSION.txt`.

Below are the contents of the 2.0.5 `VERSION.txt`:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ //
    // CakePHP Version
    //
    // Holds a static string representing the current version of CakePHP
    //
    // CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
    // Copyright 2005-2011, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
    //
    // Licensed under The MIT License
    // Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
    //
    // @copyright     Copyright 2005-2011, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
    // @link          http://cakephp.org
    // @package       cake.libs
    // @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
    // @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
    // +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    2.0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way for that is command .\cake version this cammand will show cakephp version that you used.